# Geoserver Replace wfs transaction is not working with a postgres table containing multi type geometry

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, wfs, wfs-t

Does anybody have a solution for making Geoserver work with WFS-T replace on multi-type geometry layer? When I replace any feature, it gets updated as POINT(0,0). Is it geoserver Internal problem?

WFS-T Replace

```
<wfs:Transaction
   version="2.0.0"
   service="WFS"
   xmlns:WS="WS"
   xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0
           http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
 <wfs:Replace>
   <WS:overlays gml:id="overlays.39">
     <WS:the_geom>
       <gml:MultiCurve srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/epsg/0/4326">
         <gml:curveMember>
           <gml:LineString>
             <gml:posList>-146.46 -41.24 146.57 -41.25 146.64 -41.25 146.76 -41.33</gml:posList>
           </gml:LineString>
         </gml:curveMember>
       </gml:MultiCurve>
     </WS:the_geom>
     <WS:overlayname>testing_overlay</WS:overlayname>
          <WS:style>{"someStyle":"some"}</WS:style>
          <WS:icon>someIcon</WS:icon>
     <WS:username>somename</WS:username>
   </WS:overlays>
      <fes:Filter>
    <fes:ResourceId rid="overlays.39"/>
 </fes:Filter>
 </wfs:Replace>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

describeFeatureType:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:WS="http://10.4.71.180:8180/geoserver/WS" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://10.4.71.180:8180/geoserver/WS">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://10.4.71.180:8180/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="overlaysType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="geom" nillable="false" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="overlayname" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="username" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="style" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="icon" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="overlays" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="WS:overlaysType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: you need to add the XML you are sending and the describeFeatureType response for the layer. But in general multi geometry type stores are error prone and difficult to use correctly and should be avoided/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the replace XML and describeFeatureType response.

Answer (score 1):

Your featureType has a geometry called `geom` but your transaction has a geometry called `the_geom` so it doesn't match and you get a default value.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. I missed it. It is working.